# can Ruby GTK::StatusIcon use to find existing systray icon?

Tags: ruby, gtk2, systray

I try to automate right clicking windows systemtray icon using ruby. After searching on web, I find GTK::StatusIcon can be used to create NEW systray icon and menu, etc. However, I didn't find a way to identify current/existing icons. From searching result, all posts are shown how to create new statusIcon like this:

```
si = Gtk::StatusIcon.new
si.stock = Gtk::Stock::DAILOG_INFO
si.tooltiop ='StatusIcon'
```

Is it any way to use Gtk::StatusIcon to find/click existing systray icon?

I'm new on GUI programming and GTK. Could someone point out a right direction for me?

Thanks in advance!!